# C++ Object Initialization outside main

Tags: c++

I have some C++ code that produces an error:

```
class foo{
  public:
    int a; 
    int b;
};

foo test;
test.a=1;   //error here
test.b=2;

int main()
{
    //some code operating on object test
}
```

I get this error:

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '.' token
```

What does the error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: `test.a=1;` and `test.b=2;` are invalid. You cannot do assignments outside a function.

Comment: You're not initializing it by assigning to its members.

Comment: The indentation makes it look almost as if it was Java code, with main being inside class foo..

Answer (score 3):

It's called a constructor. Include one that takes the wanted values as arguments.

Like

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo(int aa, int bb)
        : a(aa), b(bb)  // Initializer list, set the member variables
        {}

private:
    int a, b;
};

foo test(1, 2);
```

---

As noted by chris, you can also use aggregate initialization if the fields are `public`, like in your example:

```
foo test = { 1, 2 };
```

This also works in C++11 compatible compilers with the constructor as in my example.

Comment: It's also possible to use aggregate initialization.

Comment: This was my first post.. Thank you guys for the fast response

Answer (score 1):

This should be:

```
class foo
{
  public:
    int a; 
    int b;
};

foo test;
int main()
{
  test.a=1;
  test.b=2;
}
```

You can not write code outside of a method/function, you can only declare variables/classes/types, etc.

Comment: The other answers were good as well and possibly a little fancier, but I think this one was the best and most appropriate for the given context.

Answer (score 0):

You need a default constructor:

```
//add this
foo(): a(0), b(0) { };
//maybe a deconstructor, depending on your compiler
~foo() { };
```

Comment: It has a default constructor and a destructor already and the object's being zero-initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the variable initialization outside a function. As mentioned in a comment

```
test.a=1
test.b=2
```

is thus invalid. If you really need an initialization, use a constructor like

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo(const int a, const int b);

    int a;
    int b;
}
```

Otherwise you could put the initialization e.g. into the main function.